# How do I test exception *handling* in PHPUnit?

Tags: php, unit-testing, exception, phpunit

I see lots of answers about how to use PHPUnit to test whether or not an exception is thrown for a method - that's great and fine.

For this code, I understand that @expectsException will allow me to test the try{} block and thing1(). How do I test the `thing2()` and `thing3()` bits?

```
try {
 thing1();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
 thing2();
 thing3();
}
```

Here's what I have now that fails:

```
function myTest() {
    $prophecy = $this->prophesize(Exception::CLASS);
    $my_exception = $prophecy->reveal();

    // more testing stuff
    ... 
}
```

PHPUnit sees the `reveal()` call as an unexpected exception, and quits before "more testing stuff".

Comment: Make a test that triggers the exception

Answer (score 2):

[The annotation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.expectedException) `expectedException` is used to declare, that test will be **finished** with unhandled exception.

In your case, as **Ancy C** noticed, `thing1()` must throw any Exception and then `thing2()` and `thing3()` will be called and you can test them.

---

**Edit:**

You must have an error somewhere. This is working perfectly for me

```
<?php

class Stack
{
    public function testMe()
    {
        try {
            $this->thing1();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return $this->thing2();
        }
    }

    private function thing1()
    {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    private function thing2()
    {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

And test class:

```
class StackTest extends TestCase
{
    public function test()
    {
        $stack = new Stack();
        $result = $stack->testMe();

        self::assertEquals(2, $result);
    }
}
```

Result:

```
PHPUnit 5.5.4 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.                                                                   1 / 1 (100%)

Time: 20 ms, Memory: 4.00MB

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)
```

Comment: When thing1() throws an exception, phpunit sees it as a failure and quits, rather than moving on to the catch() statement. How do I get around this?

Comment: @aaronbauman I've added some working example. Try to do sth similar.

Comment: @aaronbauman You can show more code and we can think together